# "command not found: mongod" error despite updating PATH

Tags: mongodb, bash, macos, macos-catalina

I have added this line

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:"/Users/pouya/mongodb/bin:$PATH"
```

to my `.bash_profile`, but I still get this error:

```
zsh: command not found: mongod
```

I use macOS Catalina, and this happened to me with MongoDB.

I can't use Brew because of restrictions on my country and I want to install MongoDB manually, how can I do that?

Comment: `.bash_profile` is probably not run when zsh is starting, you have to update `PATH` in the corresponding file for zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For macOS Catalina the zsh is the default shell, so you should at this line to ~/.zshrc file

```sh
vim ~/.zshrc

export PATH=$PATH:"/Users/pouya/mongodb/bin:$PATH"


source ~/.zshrc
```